# Get variable from a string

Tags: javascript, eval

Does anyone know how could I select a variable from a String in JavaScript? Here's what I'm basically trying to achieve:

```
var myLang = "ESP";

var myText_ESP = "Hola a todos!";
var myText_ENG = "Hello everybody!";

console.log(myText_ + myLang); // This should trace "Hola a todos!"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [jQuery Language Switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427723/jquery-language-switcher).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var hellos = {
    ESP: 'Hola a todos!',
    ENG: 'Hello everybody!'
};

var myLang = 'ESP';

console.log(hellos[myLang]);
```

I don't like putting everything in global scope, and then string accessing window properties; so here is another way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If your variable is defined in the global context, you may do this :

```
console.log(window['myText_' + myLang]);
```

Comment: Thanks man, you just saved my life and that of my neurons! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myLang = "ESP";

var myText = {
    ESP : "Hola a todos!",
    ENG : "Hello everybody!"
}

console.log(myText[myLang]); // This should trace "Hola a todos!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` for that but this is very bad practice:

```
console.log(eval("myText_" + myLang);
```

I'll suggest to have an object instead:

```
var myLang = "ESP";
var texts = {
    'ESP': "Hola a todos!",
    'ENG': "Hello everyboy!"
};
console.log( texts[ myLang ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good pratice, but you can try using `eval()` function.

```
var myLang = "ESP";

var myText_ESP = "Hola a todos!";
var myText_ENG = "Hello everyboy!";

console.log(eval('myText_' + myLang));
```

Comment: `eval()` is really powerful, but it's worth noting that its power can be abused. It can be a security (and code maintenance) liability.

Comment: Thank for the commend Richard. THis is the reason why I said it is not  a good pratice. :)