# JavaScript: access array with the same name as a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get variable from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882215/get-variable-from-a-string)

I have an array called *myArray* and a variable which is called *myVar*. The myVar variable holds a value 'myArray' (value of myVar equals the arrays name). Can I somehow access the arrays elements using the myVar variable? Some code to explain what I mean:

```
var myArray = {1, 2, 3};
var myVar = "myArray";
```

Thanks!

Comment: "*I have an array called myArray*". In JavaScript, arrays can't have a name. The array you have is anonymous.

Comment: Show pseudo code of what you mean.

Comment: I added some code above.

Comment: `myarray = {}` isn't an array, it's an object BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key here is [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

If `myArray` is global

```
var myArray  = ["1","2","3"];
var myVar = "myArray";
console.log(window[myVar]);
```

better to use a namespace

```
var myData = {};
myData.myArray  = ["1","2","3"];
var myVar = "myArray";
console.log(myData[myVar]);
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds. Darn. (not that it's a competition, just found it funny our variance is numbers vs. letters. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If your array (`myArray`) is a global variable, then you can use `window[myVar]`. If it is a local variable, then the only way is to use `eval(myVar)` (or its analogs).

```
arr = window[myVar] // assuming myArray is a global variable
arr[0] = 5 // same as myArray[0] = 5
```